# Definition of 'dense' in topology

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Assuming that X is a metric space where $E \in X$, Nr(p) stands for the ball of center p and radius r and E′ is the set of limit points (i.e. the cluster points) of E,

The rudin book I have says 'E is *dense* in X if every point of X is a limit point of E, or a point of E (or both), so basically if $X = E\cup E'$. 
 
However, the professor gives the definition as '$E \subset X$ is dense in X if $\forall p\in X, \forall r > 0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \iff X = E \cup E'$. 
 
But isn't  $\forall p\in X, \forall r > 0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \iff X = E'$ ? 
 
So I thought the professor's definition is not enough for that of 'dense'. Is my understanding correct? If not, I'd like to know where the flaw is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A nice question! You should mention the definition of $E'$?!

Comment: What is $E'$? Without knowing what it is, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: What do you mean by $$\forall p\in X, \forall r > 0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \iff X \in E'?$$ What does the $X\in E'$ mean at the end? Did you mean $X=E'$?

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the definition of a limit point requires that $p\neq q$ in your nomenclature. For example, if $X=[1,2]$, and $E=\{1\}$, then $E'=\emptyset$, $1$ isn't a limit point of $E$, but of course every neighborhood of $1$ contains $1$.

So for a more complicated example, if $X=\{0\} \cup [1,2]$ and $E=\{0\} \cup ([1,2] \cap \mathbb Q)$. You want $E$ to be dense in $X$, but $0$ is not going to be a limit point of any subset of $X$. That's why you "have to" include $E$ as well, to get the "usual sense" of dense.

Answer (score 2):

If by $E'$ you mean the set of limit points of $E$, then the statement

$$\forall p\in X, \forall r > 0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \iff X = E'$$

is wrong. For example, take $X=\mathbb R$ with the standard metric, and $E=\{0\}$.

Then, $E'=\emptyset$, but the set $X=\{0\}$ satisfies the condition

$$\forall p\in X, \forall r > 0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p)$$

This is because, if $p\in X$, then $x=0$. Then, if $r>0$, we can take $q=0$, and have $q\in N_r(p)$.

---

The definition of a limit point is:

> For a set $E$, $p$ is a limit point of $E$ if, for every $r>0$, there exists some $q\in E$ such that $q\in N_r(p)$ **and** $q\neq p$.

That last condition, $q\neq p$, is important.

Answer (score 0):

So after all, it seems like the professor was sort of right in what he said and my equivalence was flawed.

First of all,
$\forall p \in X, \forall r>0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \wedge q \neq p \iff X \subseteq E'$ , as pointed out by multiple answers. 
 So the condition $p \neq q$ is obviously crucial in the above equivalence. 
 
Next, regarding the professor's definition, he was right in saying that 
$\forall p \in X, \forall r>0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_r(p) \iff$ E is dense in X.  
 
It is because $\forall p \in X, \forall r>0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \wedge q \neq p \iff X \subseteq E' \cdots (a)$ 
$\forall p \in X, \forall r>0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \wedge q=p \iff \forall p \in X, p \in E \iff X \subseteq E \cdots (b)$ 
With (a) and (b) combined, then 
 $\forall p \in X, \forall r>0, \exists q \in E: q \in N_{r}(p) \iff X \subseteq E \cup E'$, 
 which means that every element of X is either a limit point of E or an element of E (or both), which fits in the Rudin's definition of density.